# Java EE, Spring core/web. Как правильно настроить application context с помощью аннотаций?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, java-ee, аннотации

Допустим, имеем следующую структуру классов:

- `User` (entity)
- `UserDAO` (data layer)
- `UserService` (service)
- `UserAdapter` (adapter for user entity (DTO) (передается через слоя
  приложения, не совсем понимаю для чего это))
- `MainController` (Servlet)

Как все это взаимодействует между собой я +- понимаю, но совершенно не могу понять как это дело сконфигурировать с помощью аннотаций (`Java Bean`):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
```

Собственно возник ряд вопросов:

1. Какие аннотации к какому из представленных классов использовать и
   почему?
2. Как все это дело прикрутить к web.xml?
3. Нужно ли создавать отдельный класс-context и описывать зависимости
   там?
4. Вызывается ли конструктор класса (например - UserService) при
   инициализации его как Bean?

Очень буду рад каким либо конкретным примерам инициализации всего этого чуда, ежели примеры еще и с пояснениями будут - рад буду в двойне.